# Escaping from sudo within a script

Tags: bash, unix, homebrew

I have a script that calls another script as sudo. From within the second script, I want to be able to run another process *without* sudo permissions (the process in question is `brew`, which doesn't play nicely with `sudo`).

Here's the code in question:

scriptA.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo ./scriptB.sh
```

scriptB.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This runs as sudo, but I need it to run as a regular user e.g. `username`
brew update
```

I tried `su -c "brew update" -s /bin/sh username`, but OS X's `su` doesn't allow the `c` flag.

Comment: It's possible that you don't want to run all of `scriptB.sh` with `sudo`, just certain commands inside the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `sudo` *again*:

```
sudo -u username brew update
```

Answer (score 0):

Superuser can use the `su` command to become any other user. So

```
su otheruser -c "command to execute"
```

OS X `su` does allow the `-c` option. You just have to put it after the username. From the man page:

> If the optional args are provided on the command line, they are passed to the login shell of the target login.  Note that all command line arguments before the target login name are processed by su itself, everything after the target login name gets passed to
>        the login shell.

In this case `-c` is not an option to the `su` command, it's an option to the login shell. And most shells take a `-c` option to specify a command to execute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But like I had mentioned in the post, `su` doesn't accept the `-c` option on OS X.

Comment: I tested it and it does. You forgot to put the username in the command when you tried it.